# I have doubts about the Github licensing issue

Tags: licensing

I will go straight to the point, I already read the terms I looked for some information on the issue of licenses I looked at sites but nothing, I did not understand anything is that I have a project that is totally done by me, but I want anyone who dares to share or do something to dump the credits on me, what license do I use for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "dump the credits on me"? You mean you want any derivative works to also belong to you? Or do you just want attribution in derivative works?

Answer (score 2):

Given the broadest interpretation of your question, the MIT License is the simplest license that would meet your stated requirements. The text is archived [here](https://mit-license.org/). It is very brief and has clear requirements.

Your rather inimical language here:

> I want anyone who dares to share or do something to dump the credits on me ...

would seem to imply that you are not comfortable with others using, modifying, distributing, etc. the code from your project. I would suggest not distributing the source of your project openly, if that is the case.

Edit: I just remembered: github has created [choosealicense.com](https://choosealicense.com/), which helps you select a license by a step-by-step process, given some requirements.

Comment: It's a good idea to not answer vague, heavily down-voted and close-voted questions because they will be deleted. The OP has obviously not returned since posting and doesn't care about refining their question.

Comment: That's ok. It doesn't bother me, and it may help someone.

Comment: My point is that your answer rewards the users who ask low quality questions; that's not what SE is about.

Comment: English might not be the OP's first language, and he might be busy otherwise. Even if that's not the case, your contention is unnecessary. I'm not sure by what metric I've "rewarded" the OP, nor does it bother me. I had a moment free, and produced an answer that might help the OP. The down-votes and risk of deletion would seem to make the issue moot otherwise. Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: I think that this answer was helpful, and this question should not be deleted. (If it is deleted, I will probably vote to reopen.)